# set uiimageview from saved camera roll reference url

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, alassetslibrary

There might be something I don't yet understand in how the assets-library works with reference urls but I'm saving the reference in nsdefaults for now.  I want to show the image from the reference when the screen loads but it's not working.  Here's how I'm getting the image:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] forKey:@"profilePic"];
  [pics addObject:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];
  [library assetForURL:[pics objectAtIndex:pics.count-1] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){
      UIImage *copyofOriginal = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation]fullScreenImage] scale:0.5 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
      profilePic.image = copyofOriginal;
  }failureBlock:nil];
}
```

Now when the app starts up again, I'm trying to get it back like this but it's giving me a blank image:

```
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"profilePic"] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [library assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"profilePic"]] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){
        UIImage *copyofOriginal = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation]fullScreenImage] scale:0.5 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        profilePic.image = copyofOriginal;
    }failureBlock:nil];
}
```

Logging the [info objectForKey: UIImage...] and the saved value from NSUserDefaults gives me the exact same reference url.  How come it's not setting?

Comment: Maybe this article may help you: http://www.wooptoot.com/loading-images-from-the-ios-photo-library

Comment: Saw it already, not exactly what I'm trying to do.  That just deals with initially picking the image.  What I want to do is save the reference after initially picking it and setting it using the reference url

Answer (score 1):

**How To Let User Select An Image From Gallery?**

Imagine you have controller MyDummyController which shows a button “Pick An Image”. You’d like to open phone Gallery when that button is tapped. First make sure that your controller implements UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.

```
@interface MyDummyController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Next, implement following methods in your implementation file.

```
    // make sure this method is invoked when you tap "Pick An Image" button
-(void)onTapPickAnImage
{
   UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   imagePicker.delegate = self;
   imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
   [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
       // here is the image user selected
       UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
       // here is the URL to the image
       NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
    }
```

**How To Extract String Reference From The Image URL?**

In different persistence systems, for example Core Data, you cannot save an NSURL directly. Which means, if you want to store reference of selected image somewhere, you’ll need it in a string. It can be done like below:

```
NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
NSString *ref = url.absoluteString;
// now you can persist your string reference somewhere
```

**How To Load Image Again Using String Reference?**

```
// here we are loading the string reference to image we want to load
NSString *ref = [self loadMyImageRef]; // loadMyImageRef is a dummy method, you can put your implementation here

// ALAssetsLibrary provides a way to access photos/videos in gallery programmatically
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ref] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
   // here we have received the image data, now you can easily display it wherever you like
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage];
   NSLog(@"Image loaded successfully!");
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"An error occurred while loading image: %@", error.description);
}];
```

**Source:**

http://www.to-string.com/2014/04/30/how-to-extract-string-reference-to-an-image-in-ios-and-then-load-the-image-later/